# How can I use the next/image for an image where I don't know the width and height?

Tags: next.js

I want to place an image in a div, but I only want to specify the width and keep the aspect ratio. Here is my code:

```
<motion.div
                initial={{ opacity: 0, transform: "translateZ(0)" }}
                animate={{ opacity: 1, transform: "translateZ(0)" }}
                transition={{ duration: 1, ease: 'easeInOut' }}
                className='w-[400px] md:w-[500px] relative'>
                <Image
                    alt={nume}
                    layout="responsive"
                    objectFit="cover"
                    width={200}
                    height={200}
                    src={poza}
                />
            </motion.div>
```

What should I do to not get this warning in the console?

```
Image with src "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...." has legacy prop "objectFit". Did you forget to run the codemod?
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `objectFit` property is deprecated according to the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image).

If you search for objectFit, you'll see that they suggest implementing this way:

```
    style={{objectFit: "contain"}}
```

Comment: That's not working because of layout property. Also, haven't you seen that I use tailwind?

Comment: No, I am not familiar with Tailwind. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: You should check tailwind, because it removes the need of css files